# DAO classes with CRUD methods VS. DAO classes with entity-specific methods

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dao

I was wondering which is the *correct* way for creating a DAO pattern between the 2 options I explain below.

#### Scenario

I have a web application for a cinema, with entities like `Film` and `Showing`. It is a PHP application, but I think this question is relevant to any OO programming language...

#### Option A: only CRUD

Create a single `DAOInterface` class defining CRUD methods `insert`, `get`, `update` and `delete`, and implement that interface in classes like `FilmDAO` and `ShowingDAO`.
This way I will use the same method `get` to retrieve "*all films for today*" or "*all films of a given genre*", so I need to set some array of arguments to decide which entities to retrieve...

#### Option B: entity-specific methods

Create different interfaces like `FilmDAOInt` and `ShowingDAOInt`, defining methods specific to each concrete entity, such as `getFilmsByDate`, `getFilmsByGenre`, `getShowingsWithDiscount`, etc...

#### Question

Is this just a matter of taste, or is any of these approaches better than the other? And why?

Comment: The last time I worked with Hibernate for instance, concrete DAOs would decorate a generic DAO for static typing during run- and compile time, but a flexible core for the underlying persistence layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal application, where you control both the data and other layers and the data layer is used only in that application (as opposed to being a library), the rest of your application should interact only with entity-specific interfaces designed to fit the application's needs. There are many reasons:

- The rest of your application will often need to do things in the data layer which can't be done efficiently through the basic CRUD methods. You might need a report that maps well to a SQL `group by`, for example.
- Even if the basic CRUD methods can do anything that other layers need (perhaps they take query language fragments, for example), using them would require other layers to know about the database structure.
- For any given entity type, some CRUD methods might be invalid. Maybe your application stores logs, and it's forbidden to update or delete a log line. Not exposing methods to do so to the rest of the application is a good way to enforce that.
- For any given entity type, some CRUD methods might not be needed. If they're not needed, don't write them.
- Entity-specific DAOs have more methods than CRUD DAOs, but they get the job done with less total method calls from other layers and their parameters are simpler (no query language fragments, for example). They are therefore easier to stub and mock in tests.

Of course, it is common for entity-specific classes which use something like an ORM framework to automatically have all basic CRUD methods and then have entity-specific methods added by the programmer. In that case it is usually not worth the effort to have a separate entity-specific layer which hides the DAO layer; one usually just employs code standards to require the rest of the application to use only entity-specific methods or those basic CRUD methods which don't leak knowledge of the database. This unfortunately requires discipline, as anyone knows who has seen a Rails application with controllers full of ActiveRecord queries.

Answer (score 2):

Or even combine both, you would have an interface hierarchy and a parallel concrete class hierarchy i.e.

In pseudo-code:

```
// generic Dao interface applies to any Dao
interface IGenericDao[T] {
   findById(Long Id): T
   findAll(): List[T]
   countAll(): Integer
   delete(Id: Long)
   create(element: T)
   modify(Id: Long, modification: T)
}

// offers everything from IGenericDao plus Film-specific
interface IFilm extends IGenericDao[Film] {
   findByName(filmName: String): List[Film]
}

// offers everything from IGenericDao plus Showing-specific
interface IShowing extends IGenericDao[Showing] {
   findByDayAndTime(when: Timestamp): List[Showing]
}

class GenericDao[T] implements IGenericDao[T] { ... }
class FilmDao extends GenericDao[Film] implements IFilm { ... }
class ShowingDao extends GenericDao[Showing] implements IShowing { ... }
```